# How to force Visual Studio 2008 to regenerate code from T4 templates when an XML file changes?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-generation, t4

I'm generating quite a bit of code from a single XML file, but the templates are organized in two different T4 templates. Whenever I change the XML file, I have to remember to open the two `*.tt` files, change them trivially (add / delete a space) and save them again to make sure the code is generated.

This can't be the right way to do it!

Ideally, I would like Visual Studio 2008 to do a text transfor on the T4 files if the XML file has changed. I'm a bit lost since I don't really know how Visual Studio builds C# projects, so pointers in that direction would also be of help (I could then try to figure it out myself).

Comment: BTW: I figured out hot Visual Studio builds C# projects: MSBuild. The project file itself (*.csproj) is an MSBuild file, akin to a Makefile. So, a solution might be to touch the *.tt files when "building" the XML file... I'll keep you posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use T4ScriptFileGenerator from  [T4Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com) as a custom tool for your XML file. Let's say you have Test.XML file in your project with this custom tool. The first time Test.XML is saved, this custom tool create a new Test.tt file. You can place your code generation logic there (in place, or #include your other .tt files). Next time you save Test.XML it will transform (generate code from) the existing Test.tt.

Answer (score 2):

I think I might finally have found a solution here. I got the idea when browsing how XAML files are mentioned in the project file for c# projects.

Let us assume a file `A.tt` and `B.tt` that use data from `C.xml` and we would like to regenerate the code whenever `C.xml` changes.

Edit the project file. Your definitions for `A.tt` and `B.tt` should look something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="A.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>A.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <DependentUpon>C.xml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
    <None Include="B.tt">
      <Generator>TextTemplatingFileGenerator</Generator>
      <LastGenOutput>B.cs</LastGenOutput>
      <DependentUpon>C.xml</DependentUpon>
    </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

Further, you will need (of course...)

```
<ItemGroup>
    <None Include="C.xml" />
</ItemGroup>
```

And also the instruction to autogenerate `A.cs` and `B.cs`:

```
<Compile Include="A.cs">
      <DependentUpon>A.tt</DependentUpon>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
</Compile>
<Compile Include="B.cs">
      <DependentUpon>B.tt</DependentUpon>
      <AutoGen>True</AutoGen>
      <DesignTime>True</DesignTime>
</Compile>
```

I believe most of this will already be done for you when you create the template file, so all you really have to add is the `<DependentUpon>C.xml</DependentUpon>` parts to the `ItemGroup`s for `A.tt` and `B.tt`.

Comment: It would make a lot of sense if this was correct. Sadly it is not :( - DependentUpon is apparently only used for presentation purposes in the project tree view.

Comment: @Ibmurai, yes, I found that too... I just didn't have any definite proof and just moved on. thank you for pointing this out!